# Query Editor cannot connect to Azure DB anymore

Tags: azure-sql-database

Before, I used the Query Editor to make some query on my Azure DB, but since some days, it's not working anymore.
Databases are on an SQL Database Server on my Azure Subscription.
To query or modify columns / tables I use Query Editor on portal.azure.com

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Could you please elaborate and specify which DB using you are using and with which API you have created the DB. e.g Cosmos Db with SQL API. That would help us digging deep into the issue.

Comment: I've add precisions upside :)

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: I've juste tryied to reproduce and now it's working

Comment: when I select Query Editor on my Databases, then connect with a login, it was taking long time and crash, and now, it works... strange

Comment: @EmmanuelLehmann Sometimes, I also have the same error, you can see my answer.  If it helps,  please mark it as the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When we open a new query editor with SSMS, it shows us: `disconnect`:

[image]

And after a while, it will try to connect to the database:
[image]

Sometimes, I also have the same error. The query editor has opened for a long time and didn't use it. I reconnect the database and open a new query editor, it will works ok. As you said, you've juste tryied to reproduce and now it's working. So I think the reason is the connection lost or timeout.

Hope this helps.